# Pandas convert columns of datetime format from 31JAN2020 to 2020-01-31

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with column:

```
Date
31Jan20
31Jan20
3Mar20
3Mar20
```

I am trying to convert it to

```
Date
2020-01-31
2020-01-31
2020-03-03
2020-03-03
```

I was able to convert each date individual date by

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%d%b%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but when i try to convert column, it was not working

```
test['date_fmt']  = pd.to_datetime(test["date"].strptime('%d%b%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

> error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Can anyone kindly help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `df['Date']` directly to `pd.to_datetime` and cast the result to `str`

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce').astype(str)

Out[867]:
0    2020-01-31
1    2020-01-31
2    2020-03-03
3    2020-03-03
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

*Note*: From your codes, I assume you want the final output is string format of date.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this method previously but error message:Unknown string format

Comment: your data may have some non-date strings. use option `errors='coerce'` as I edited in my answer

Comment: Thanks Andy, with errors ='coerce', no errors reported, but the convert result was all 'NaT'  'NaT'  'NaT'  'NaT'

Comment: I am using python 2.7, by the way.

Comment: hah... it means your `Date` column is not str. Could you post output of this command: `df.Date.to_dict()` ?

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks! Andy

Comment: ohh...so your `Date`  column string is in 4-digit year as `'31Jan2020'`, not 2-digit year as your sample `31Jan20 31Jan20 3Mar20 3Mar20`. Because `%Y` is used for 4-digit year

Answer (score -1):

you can also create a new DataFrame date:

pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020',end ='1/03/2020')

more information https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html